# how to implement ASP.NET MVC 5 using Google Calendar API via OAuth 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, google-calendar-api

Google calender event can't sync into my webpage event.my referes sample is [asp.net mvc4 google calender api](http://bamboobig.blogspot.in/2014/01/aspnet-mvc-4-using-google-calendar-api.html)

**How to obtain access token?**

The above sample is event creation generated due to **angular.js** And then *event controller* is calender details are null values.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["googletoken"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

        return View();
    }


    // AJAX
    // POST:/Event/GetAll
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetAll()
    {
        var gevents = service.GetAll();

        return Json(gevents);
    }

     // AJAX
    // POST /Event/FetchGoogleCalendar
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FetchGoogleCalendar()
    {
        string token = Session["googletoken"] as string;
        var calendarList = service.GetAllGoogleCalendar(token);
        return Json(calendarList);
    }

    // AJAX
    // POST /Event/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(string calendarId, string requestBody)
    {
        string token = Session["googletoken"] as string;
        var e = service.Insert(token, calendarId, requestBody);

        return Json(e);
    }

    // AJAX
    // POST:/Event/GetEvent
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetEventByID(string id)
    {
        Guid _id;
        Guid.TryParse(id, out _id);
        if (_id == default(Guid))
            return Redirect("Index");

        var devent = service.FindAll().Where(x => x.guid == _id).SingleOrDefault();

        return Json(devent);
    }

    // AJAX
    // POST:/Event/UpdateEventByID
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateEventByID(string guid, string calendarId, string id, string requestBody)
    {
        string token = Session["googletoken"] as string;
        var updatedGvent = service.Update(token, guid, calendarId, id, requestBody);

        return Json(updatedGvent);
    }

    // AJAX
    // POST:/Event/DeleteEventByID
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DeleteEventByID(string guid, string calendarId, string id)
    {
        string token = Session["googletoken"] as string;

        var b = service.Delete(token, guid, calendarId, id);

        return Json(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check this link for Oauth 2.0 sample for calendar API in ASP.net MVC https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: that is just calender implentation.like iframe calender. i need to edit and create evets in asp.net MVC framework with google calendar api